Reducing gaps in ggplots
I have this R code about a time series plot:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
my_df <- data.frame(
    year = rep(2023, 12),
    month = 1:12,
    x1 = cumsum(runif(12, min = -10, max = 10))
)

my_df <- my_df %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(paste(year, month, "01", sep = "-"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

Now, suppose I have these 3 scenarios:
scenarios <- data.frame(
    date = seq(max(my_df$date) + months(1), by = "month", length.out = 6),
    scenario1 = c(20,21, 22, 23,24, 25),
    scenario2 = c(30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35),
    scenario3 = c(40, 41, 42, 43, 45, 45)
)

I want to make a plot of everything together:
scenarios_melted <- scenarios %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("scenario"), names_to = "scenario", values_to = "value")

ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = my_df, aes(x = date, y = x1, color = "Original Data")) +
    geom_line(data = scenarios_melted, aes(x = date, y = value, color = scenario)) +
    labs(title = "Time Series Plot of x1 with Scenarios",
         x = "Time",
         y = "x1",
         color = "Legend") +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Original Data" = "black", "scenario1" = "red", "scenario2" = "blue", "scenario3" = "green"),
                       labels = c("Original Data", "Scenario 1", "Scenario 2", "Scenario 3")) +
    theme_minimal()

The problem is that there is a big gap between where the original data finishes and the new data starts:

I want the 3 colored lines to start from where the original line ends.
How can I fix this?

I think I found something that might work? I can use the tail() function to directly add the scenarios to the final data point:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
my_df <- data.frame(
    year = rep(2023, 12),
    month = 1:12,
    x1 = cumsum(runif(12, min = -10, max = 10))
)

my_df <- my_df %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(paste(year, month, "01", sep = "-"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

last_point <- my_df %>% slice_tail(n = 1)


scenarios <- data.frame(
    date = seq(max(my_df$date) + months(1), by = "month", length.out = 6),
    scenario1 = c(20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25),
    scenario2 = c(30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35),
    scenario3 = c(40, 41, 42, 43, 45, 45)
)

scenarios <- bind_rows(
    data.frame(
        date = last_point$date,
        scenario1 = last_point$x1,
        scenario2 = last_point$x1,
        scenario3 = last_point$x1
    ),
    scenarios
)

scenarios_melted <- scenarios %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("scenario"), names_to = "scenario", values_to = "value")

ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = my_df, aes(x = date, y = x1, color = "Original Data")) +
    geom_line(data = scenarios_melted, aes(x = date, y = value, color = scenario)) +
    labs(title = "Time Series Plot of x1 with Scenarios",
         x = "Time",
         y = "x1",
         color = "Legend") +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Original Data" = "black", "scenario1" = "red", "scenario2" = "blue", "scenario3" = "green"),
                       labels = c("Original Data", "Scenario 1", "Scenario 2", "Scenario 3")) +
    theme_minimal()


Just change this line: seq(max(my_df$date) + days(10) ... You are adding 1 month, months(1), so there's a gap equal to 1 month, if you add 10 days, then the gap will be smaller.

Or you could add a break in the axis.

You might also consider binding the last actual observation to each of the scenarios, to demonstrate that they are imagined futures of the same series.
